# Failed to override styles with classes in material-ui

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I was implementing a table with [TableRow](https://material-ui.com/api/table-row/) component from material-ui, which has a property called "selected". Whenever "selected" is true, a pink background-color(from the default theme) is applied for it.
I was trying to change this default pink color, according to the docs, i chose to [override the css classes](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-class-names) like:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  rowSelected: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[700]
  }
})
class CustomTableRow extends React.Component {
// basic component logic
render() {
const {classes, className, style } = this.props;
  <TableRow
    key={key}
    component="div"
    selected={true}
    hover={true}
    className={className}
    classes={{ selected: classes.rowSelected}}
    style={style}
  >
      // some children
  </TableRow>
}
export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(CustomTableRow);
```

But this didn't work, which was very confusing. Because i had succeeded to do the same thing somewhere else for a [Drawer](https://material-ui.com/api/drawer/) component with the same method above.

I debugged every css properties with Chrome Dev Tools. What i am suspecting most now is, the pink color applied on this component with this way below:

```
.MuiTableRow-root.Mui-selected, .MuiTableRow-root.Mui-selected:hover {
    background-color: rgba(245, 0, 87, 0.16);
```

And my custom class style had lower precedence than this one, which was greyed out.

UPDATE1:

My project is too big, i don't know how to simplify it for codesandbox.io.
Maybe we can check the material-ui source code directly, [TableRow Source Code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/TableRow/TableRow.js).
What i was doing is to override this css declaration in `root`

```
    '&$selected, &$selected:hover': {
      backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.secondary.main, theme.palette.action.selectedOpacity),
    },
```

by passing in another `selected` declaration below. I realized it's because this `&$selected, &$selected:hover` is not normally css, even if i copy this into `rowSelected`, it doesn't work either.

UPDATE2:

I managed to override that backgroundColor, with '!important' keyword:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  rowSelected: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[700] + " !important",
  }
})
```

I don't know whether this is one ideal solution. This clearly shows the problem is about css classes precedence. So how to override that already defined backgroundColor in class `root` with class `selected`.

Some help please, thank you.

Comment: Would be better to help you if you have a fiddle or jsbin link with the example to modify

Answer (score 1):

To provide specifity for selected class you can apply the `$selected` and `$selected:hover` classes to your overrides like below

```
const styles = theme => ({
  rowSelected: {
    "&$selected, &$selected:hover": {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[800]
    }
  }
})
```

[Sample demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/f71wj?file=/demo.js)